# Why is plt.figure() defined outside the for loop?

Tags: python, matplotlib

In the following code why I have to define `fig` and `ax` at the beginning of for loop? When I write it at the end of loop it gives me only one graph not the two.

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
Ls = [2, 4]
for L in range(len(Ls)):
    x = np.arange(10)
    y = np.random.randint(0, 11, size=10)
    print(y)
    ax.plot(x,y)
    ax.set_label("x")
    ax.set_label("y")
    plt.savefig("jj.png")
    plt.show()
```

Comment: You only create one figure and are then you're wondering why you only get one figure?

Comment: No I should get one figure due to(111) but why I have to define ax and fig before the for loop? how its working effects when I define it after for loop?

Comment: Because you want to use `ax` _within_ the loop. How would that be possible without defining it before?

Comment: I suspect by *after the loop* wants to say "after the `for` statement, at the beginning of the loop body".

Answer (score 2):

Consider defining the figure as getting a sheet of paper to draw upon. So, if you want to draw several plots into the same diagram you need to define it once (before the loop) and draw several plot onto it (in the loop). For this to work, you need to move `savefig()` and `show` out of the loop body:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

Ls = [2, 4]
for L in range(len(Ls)):
    x = np.arange(10)
    y = np.random.randint(0, 11, size=10)
    print(y)
    ax.plot(x,y)
    ax.set_label("x")
    ax.set_label("y")

plt.savefig("jj.png")
plt.show()
```

Which will give you something like this:

[image]

If you want two plots, you can use the `subplots()` method to create several axes on which you can then call `plot()` like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 1) # This creates two axes objects, one for the upper one for the lower plot
for ax in axes:
    x = np.arange(10)
    y = np.random.randint(0, 11, size=10)
    ax.plot(x,y)
    ax.set_xlabel("x")
    ax.set_ylabel("y")

fig.tight_layout()
plt.savefig("jj.png")
plt.show()
```

This will give you something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop has two steps.

If you create `fig = plt.figure()` inside the loop, there will be two plots, one per iteration; if you put `fig = plt.figure()` outside the for loop, then `plt.plot(...)` will plot in the only figure that was created.

When the `plt.figure()` is outside the for loop, there are still two plots but one figure, but because of the line `plt.show()` one plot is replacing the other or plotting over the other.

If you delete the line `plt.show()` you'll see the two plots in the same figure.

Comment: but when I create fig = plt.figure() inside loop. I only get one plot.  I want to use same x values but different y values on the same plot

Comment: see what happens if you put the line `plt.show()` after the for loop, i mean outside of the for loop or delete it entirely